# how to show messageBox just once?

Tags: c#

newbie in learning c# here, im calculating cgpa and when user pick the number of subject they take, accordingly, the textBox will Enabled true according to the number of user subject and the rest is Enabled false. So when im clicking calculateCGPA, i want to popup message if the user input is empty but messageBox is shown x number of time according to the number that user left empty. How to get it to show only once. Tqvm in advanced. Explanation is very much appreciated.

1.CheckingUserCheckedRadioButton

```
private void DisplayTextBox(Control con)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (rad1.Checked)
            {
                if (c is TextBox)
                {
                    ((TextBox)c).Enabled = false;
                    txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
                    txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
                }
                else
                {
                    DisplayTextBox(c);
                }

            }
       }
}
```

2.DisplayingMessageBoxWhenClickingCalculate

```
private void calculate(Control con)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (c.Text == "")
                {
                    DialogResult x = new DialogResult();
                    x = MessageBox.Show("TextBox cannot be Empty");
                    if (x == DialogResult.OK)
                        txtCCode1.Focus();
                }
                else
                {
                    int totalCredHours = 0;
                    CalcTotalCredHours(credHour1, credHour2, credHour3, credHour4, credHour5, credHour6, ref totalCredHours);
                    courseGP1 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour1, gradePoint1);
                    courseGP2 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour2, gradePoint2);
                    courseGP3 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour3, gradePoint3);
                    courseGP4 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour4, gradePoint4);
                    courseGP5 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour5, gradePoint5);
                    courseGP6 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour6, gradePoint6);
                    double totalCGP = CalcTotalCGP(courseGP1, courseGP2, courseGP3, courseGP4, courseGP5, courseGP6);
                    double gpa = CalcGPA(totalCGP, totalCredHours);
                    lblGPA.Text = gpa.ToString("N");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                calculate(c);
            }
        }              
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have following lines:

```
static bool showed = false;                                 // <---- This line

private void DisplayTextBox(Control con)
{
    if (rad1.Checked)
    {
        foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                ((TextBox)c).Enabled = false;
                txtCCode1.Enabled = true;
                txtGrade1.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                DisplayTextBox(c);
            }

        }
    }
    showed = false;                                         // <---- This line
}

private void calculate(Control con)
{
    foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
    {
        if (c is TextBox)
        {
            if (c.Text == "")
            {
                if (!showed)                                // <---- This line
                {                                           // <---- This line
                    showed = true;                          // <---- This line
                    DialogResult x = new DialogResult();
                    x = MessageBox.Show("TextBox cannot be Empty");
                    if (x == DialogResult.OK)
                        txtCCode1.Focus();

                }                                           // <---- This line
            }
            else
            {
                int totalCredHours = 0;
                CalcTotalCredHours(credHour1, credHour2, credHour3, credHour4, credHour5, credHour6, ref totalCredHours);
                courseGP1 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour1, gradePoint1);
                courseGP2 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour2, gradePoint2);
                courseGP3 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour3, gradePoint3);
                courseGP4 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour4, gradePoint4);
                courseGP5 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour5, gradePoint5);
                courseGP6 = CalcCourseGradePoint(credHour6, gradePoint6);
                double totalCGP = CalcTotalCGP(courseGP1, courseGP2, courseGP3, courseGP4, courseGP5, courseGP6);
                double gpa = CalcGPA(totalCGP, totalCredHours);
                lblGPA.Text = gpa.ToString("N");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            calculate(c);
        }
    }              
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Create a method that shows the message box with a global flag:

```
bool showed = false;
private ShowMessageBox(string message)
{
    if (!showed)
         MessageBox.Show(message);
         showed = true;
}
```

In you code call this method

```
ShowMessageBox("TextBox cannot be Empty")
```

instead of

```
MessageBox.Shows("TextBox cannot be Empty")
```

Answer (score 0):

I you don't want to reshuffle your code much , the best way is to add a **break**  statement if any of the textboxes is Empty.

```
For e.g
foreach (Control c in con.Controls)
        {
            if (c is TextBox)
            {
                if (c.Text == "")
                {
                    DialogResult x = new DialogResult();
                    x = MessageBox.Show("TextBox cannot be Empty");
                    if (x == DialogResult.OK)
                        txtCCode1.Focus();
                        break;
                }
```

Comment: What about other controls? He still want to work with them.

Comment: ive tried this way before and i cant calculate the cgpa if i put the break. thanks though for helping.

Comment: Brother if a textbox is empty, what is the point of calculating wrong cgpa